# Superscripts in Mathematica. What is it?

Tags: symbols, notation

I am calculating a cross moment of a bivariate random vector from its moment generating function. The moment generating function includes the CDF of a bivariate normal distribution. After taking 2nd order mixed partial derivative of the moment generating function, I got the following result.

[image]

What does the `CDF^(0, {0, 2})` mean? Is it some second partial derivative of `CDF`?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `FullForm[ your expression ]` and you will see that it is the formal derivative of the CDF

Comment: Consider `D[f[x, {y, z}], {z, 2}]`

Comment: Thank you for all your comments!

Answer (score 2):

To understand your result you need to understand that Mathematica does not know how to take effectively the derivative w.r.t the parameters of the CDF.

Let us start with the PDF:

```
tt = PDF[
   MultinormalDistribution[{Subscript[\[Mu], 1], Subscript[\[Mu], 
     2]}, {{Subscript[\[Sigma], 
      1]^2, \[Rho] Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] Subscript[\[Sigma], 
       2]}, {\[Rho] Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] Subscript[\[Sigma], 2], 
      Subscript[\[Sigma], 2]^2}}], {x, y}];
```

Then

```
D[tt, \[Rho]][[1]]
```

[image]
Conversely, if we use the CDF

```
  tt = CDF[
   MultinormalDistribution[{Subscript[\[Mu], 1], Subscript[\[Mu], 
     2]}, {{Subscript[\[Sigma], 
      1]^2, \[Rho] Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] Subscript[\[Sigma], 
       2]}, {\[Rho] Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] Subscript[\[Sigma], 2], 
      Subscript[\[Sigma], 2]^2}}], {x, y}];
```

The derivative remains symbolic

```
  D[tt, \[Rho]][[1]]
```

[image]

Note that in 1D it works

```
 tt = CDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x];
     D[tt, \[Sigma]] // FullSimplify;
```

[image]

**Update**

To answer the meaning of the `{1,{0,0}}` exponent, one needs to understand here that the  CDF takes 3 arguments, namely the Distribution and the pair of variables, in our case, `{x,y}`.
So  here the exponent means differentiating the CDF w.r.t. its first argument, the Distribution.

In other words what you are seeing is a special case of

```
D[CDF[distrib[a], {x,y}], a]
```

which is formally correct.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand that. But my question is how to interpret the notation. What do numbers in (1, {0, 0}) mean? In my case, I know CDF^(0, {0, 2}) should be some partial derivative, but what is the order of the derivative, and what variable or parameter is the derivative w.r.t.?

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. It's very helpful!!!